# GitLab: affect job configuration from job script

Tags: configuration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a GitLab CI configuration that looks essentially like this:

```
build:
  stage: build
  image: my_image:latest
  script:
    - /var/scripts/build_python_package.sh
```

It's extremely simple by design - the idea is that anyone in our organization can create a new repository containing a Python package, put this minimal `.gitlab-ci.yml` pipeline config in it, and this enables our "standard process" for building & testing Python packages, `develop` and `master` branches get published to our artifact repositories (in Nexus), etc.

Now I would like to add some more things to this setup, e.g.

- caching of package dependencies installed via `pip` or for faster build times (this isn't a huge problem for Python actually, but we also have R packages using a similar setup, and R packages are always built from source, so the build times get very very long.)
- designation of a directory for artifacts (handy when not on `develop` or `master` but you still want to make the package artifact available)

This seems to require going through all the `.gitlab-ci.yml` files in various projects to add entries like [`cache`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cache) or [`artifacts`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts) to the CI configuration - but this is undesirable, because we have dozens of such projects, and we want them to get the enhanced behavior without updating each project every time we come up with an improvement to our standard build process.

Ideally, we'd have the `build_python_package.sh` script somehow tell GitLab these facts.  E.g. "I just created artifacts in this directory" or "I downloaded/built some dependency packages and they should be cached".  Is that possible to do?

Failing that, is there some way to "import" a common configuration into all our package configuration files, so we can maintain a configuration centrally rather than spreading identical config around many projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using GitLab Premium, in that case, you could use a public repository as central configuration repository, then include what you need from there.

The only disadvantages I see are:
- Public repository readable by anyone inside your organization
- If the code on the public repository is corrupted, then all the pipelines who are using it are broken

Have a look at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a great solution.  We're using a self-managed instance, so it looks like it's available to us too.